# How do I return result from a spirngEventListener

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I was trying to use spring's eventLisnter in spring-boot 1.3.5.RELEASE.

I was wondering if there is a standard way to return saved object back, or return more information after event was processed.

I may use event as a container to set my saved object back, but I am not sure if this is the best practice, any advice will be appreciated:)

Here is the example:

```
public class StoreOrderEvent extends ApplicationEvent {

    private OrderBean orderBean;

    /**
     * Create a new ApplicationEvent.
     *
     * @param source the object on which the event initially occurred (never {@code null})
     */
    public StoreOrderEvent (Object source, OrderBean orderBean) {
        super(source);
        this.orderBean = orderBean;
    }

    public OrderBean getOrderBean() {
        return this.orderBean;
    }

}

@Component
public class OrderEventListener{

    @Autowired
    private OrderRepository orderRepository;

    @Order(5000)
    @TransactionalEventListener
    public void processStoreOrderEvent(StoreOrderEvent event) {
        OrderBean orderbean = orderRepository.save(event.getOrderBean());
        // return orderBean
    }   
}

@Service
public class OrderService{

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public OrderBean storeOrder(OrderVO vo) {
        vo -> orderBean;
        applicationContext.publishEvent(new StoreOrderEvent(this, orderBean));
        // get my saved orderBean
    }   
}
```

Comment: No, this is a bad way of doing things. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @OrangeDog I am trying to get my saved orderBean's id in Service and save it in other beans/tables.

Comment: No, what are you *actually* trying to achieve.

Comment: okay, they whole idea is different customers want to custom some actions after they saved Order,  but we don't want to satisfy a customer then add code to our common method.   like storeOrderEvent was processed, they want we post id or PO number back to their system, so we will have a customEventListener triggered by StoreOrderEvent to do that, that's why I am trying to use event and eventListener

Comment: Then why are you calling the repository from the event listener (where this custom callback should be) rather than the service?

Comment: Yes, rather than service. Because service is not easy to do customization. but eventListener could listen to event and process it by order, so common one will be triggered and custom one will be triggered after it. For service, I think it's doable, but we need to call a method much more like an adapter to identify which customer and method should be call next, not like event, we will only need to care about the customEventListener,  and we will not need to touch base/common code. Safe for other customers.

Comment: When you say "store" do you mean as in "a shop" or "to store some data"? When you say "order" do you mean as in "a purchase order" or "X before Y"? Is this custom processing asynchronous or are you supposed to be waiting for it to finish?

Comment: Sorry for confusing, it's savePurchaseOrderEvent. Normally the custom processing has to be sync, but the sendEmailEvent or post PO Number to 3rd party will be async, I mean if it doesn't have to be in the same transaction. PS. I got this idea from an old app that I've been worked, they enhanced java's eventListener. I don't remember the code, but I think they are using observer mode, one publisher to many subscribers. Now I am trying to use it in my spring project, and spring has this event and eventLisntener mechanism.

Comment: Then why don't you save first in the service then post the event. What's so difficult?

Comment: I see, you're brilliant. So forget about this event and listener stuff. Do you have any ideas about having a custom service after a common service and not invade common service's code. **Here**, what I am thinking is a factory service, which produce custom services that named with a unique name and implement the same interface as common service, and it will be put in the end of the service code, ugly but doable, still want to have a way like register a custom service for a common service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed with OrangeDog on comments. it's good to use service and then post event.
or Might use service and use ServiceLocatorFactoryBean to get custom service.